# order of definition of functions gives different results for c++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider those two programs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

void bar(int) {}

template <typename T, typename U>
void bar(std::pair<T, U>) {}

template <typename T>
concept foo = requires(const T& x)
{
    { bar(x) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << foo<int> << '\n';
  std::cout << foo<std::pair<int, double>>;
}
```

and the other one, where I just moved the definition of the two `bar()` functions after the concept definition of `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
concept foo = requires(const T& x)
{
    { bar(x) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

void bar(int) {}

template <typename T, typename U>
void bar(std::pair<T, U>) {}

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << foo<int> << '\n';
  std::cout << foo<std::pair<int, double>>;
}
```

The first programs prints `true` for both functions. However, the second prints `false`.

I don't understand why it behaves like this. I'd except the checking of the existence of the function `bar` for the given type `T` to happen just when the instantiation of the concept takes place. The concept shouldn't even compile when it isn't instantiated.

Is this defined behaviour? It seems for me that it takes the idea concept, which is defining traits a type should fit, ad absurdum as I'd have to define all functions before the concept. This would make defining concepts in a library to use them when working with the library impossible. I've tested this with g++ v 10.2.

Comment: This isn't concept related. Two-phase lookup is still two-phase lookup